# Links to chat have disappeared from main?

Tags: discussion, bug

I have noticed in the last week or two, though I am not totally sure about the timeline, that the links to chat in the right hand navigation pane of the main site have vanished.

They used to be somewhere below the yellow features box and above the HNQ list.

Just curious if I am the only one.  They appear to show up on meta still.

Comment: Ok...maybe I just hadn't been paying attention but I now see them on occasion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I still see it if I'm already in chat when Main is (re)loaded.

Taken just now:

[image]

Comment: As can be seen on the screenshot I am currently in the chat, but I don't see the links right now. I tried rejoining, but I am still not seeing the boxes.

Comment: @Secespitus Huh, interesting. I reloaded main, and the boxes went away. I reloaded a few more times, and they eventually came back. Sometimes I see an ad instead of the boxes. Very undependable. That's why I always use the chat option from the site menu.

Comment: Yeah, I tried looking out for it after *Great James* posted this and seems to sometimes be there and sometimes not. I am using an Ad-Blocker though, so it's either there or nothing is there. You mentioned an ad - is there an ad too when the chat boxes are there or is it maybe toggling through a handful of ads and the chat boxes every x minutes?

Comment: I sometimes see them and sometimes don't; it feels pretty flaky to me.  I haven't been paying close attention to whether the behavior is the same across all sites I'm active on.